# C# Attempt to Return Generic List "Cannot implictly convert type"

Tags: c#, xml, generics

(https://github.com/tommcclean/XContext)

I am writing a library that stores and retrieves data using XML Files on the File System. A Class called XMemory is supposed to hold the values once retrieved like a cache.

Step 1: Load XML File from any Object. Using Serialised XML stored in a file.

```
DemoEntity.
```

Step 2: Deserialise XML into a List of the Object.

```
List<DemoEntity>.
```

Step 3: Store List of Object in a Class Property for Later Retrieval.

Problem: I am using T to allow me to pass in objects at runtime. I cannot retrieve from the List in memory and return as a List.

Note: XEntity is an Interface which any supported object must implement in order to use this library.

```
internal class XMemory
{
    private List<List<XEntity>> EntityContents { get; set; } = new List<List<XEntity>>();

    internal List<T> Read<T>()
    {
        var entityContent = EntityContents.FirstOrDefault();

        return entityContent;
    }
}
```

The error reads "Cannot implictly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of generics here. Do you have a practical example?

Comment: I want to be able to add this Library as a reference in other projects. This project will not be aware of the objects created in my other projects. So I am using T for that reason. So I can create an object and have the library serialise it to XML and later retrieve it

Comment: Sorry if I am not able to explain the problem well. I have added a link to my project if that helps (https://github.com/tommcclean/XContext) The Demo project highlights what I am trying to achieve

Comment: It's confusing but I think what you want is `return EntityContents.First().Cast<T>().ToList()`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, thats exactly what I wanted. Can you post as an answer so I can mark the problem as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler has no way to know that whatever inside of `EntityContents` is an instance of `T`. Because of that, you need to cast the values explicitly:

```
internal List<T> Read<T>()
{
    return EntityContents.First().Cast<T>().ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should state the the type `T`  should implement (if we are speaking for an interface) ot inherit (if we are speaking for a class) the `XEntity`:

```
internal List<T> Read<T>() where T : XEntity
{
    var entityContent = EntityContents.FirstOrDefault();

    return entityContent;
}
```

Despite the fact that the above change would make the code to compile successfully, I can't understand the purpose of your class and it's method.

Answer (score 0):

Your function always returns `List<XEntity>` while you have written that it can return `List<T>`. So `T` can be not `XEntity`.

I will advise you to make this class generic and return it's T:

```
internal class XMemory<T>
{
    private List<List<T>> EntityContents { get; set; } = new List<List<T>>();

    internal List<T> Read<T>()
    {
        var entityContent = EntityContents.FirstOrDefault();

        return entityContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not able to do this because XMemory is supposed to store the contents of lots of different objects. That is why I tried to use an Interface to provide a common element to all of the objects. If I do this change I can only ever store one type.